# Python 3.4 : match from csv and return new csv with matched values

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

## QUESTION

How can I scan the reader csv for any items in the reader2 csv and return a new csv with the matched information.

## Reader2 csv format

```
66740,1800,1001463,1467373,896159
```

## reader csv format

```
1001385|NORTHWEST PIPE CO|10-Q|2015-05-06|edgar/data/1001385/0001193125-15-174814.txt
1001426|PERICOM SEMICONDUCTOR CORP|10-Q|2015-05-05|edgar/data/1001426/0001145443-15-000628.txt
1001463|Acacia Diversified Holdings, Inc.|10-K|2015-05-20|edgar/data/1001463/0001185185-15-001386.txt
1001463|Acacia Diversified Holdings, Inc.|10-K|2015-05-20|edgar/data/1001463/0001185185-15-001394.txt
1001463|Acacia Diversified Holdings, Inc.|10-Q|2015-05-20|edgar/data/1001463/0001185185-15-001388.txt
1001463|Acacia Diversified Holdings, Inc.|10-Q|2015-05-20|edgar/data/1001463/0001185185-15-001390.txt
1001463|Acacia Diversified Holdings, Inc.|10-Q|2015-05-20|edgar/data/1001463/0001185185-15-001392.txt
1001463|Acacia Diversified Holdings, Inc.|10-Q|2015-05-20|edgar/data/1001463/0001185185-15-001396.txt
```

## Current Code

```
with open('newCIK.csv') as reader2:
    reader2 = csv.reader(reader2)

    with open('search.file') as f_in, open('SP500_10K.csv', 'w') as f_out:
        reader = csv.reader(f_in, delimiter='|')
        writer = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter='|')

        for line in reader:
            for cik in reader2:
                if cik in line:
                    writer.writerow(line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to treat a file object as a list, looping over it more than once. That won't work without doing extra work. Moreover, you are not looping over the columns of the one row; you are trying to test if the *whole row* is in the other CSV file rows. You'd want to test each value, and then only against the last column of the rows in the `search.file` CSV data.

File objects have a *file position*; as you read from the file the position moves from start to end. Once at the end *it won't move to the start again automatically*.

You could seek the file object to the start again:

```
with open('newCIK.csv') as reader2_file:
    reader2 = csv.reader(reader2_file)

    with open('search.file') as f_in, open('SP500_10K.csv', 'w') as f_out:
        reader = csv.reader(f_in, delimiter='|')
        writer = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter='|')

        for line in reader:
            reader2_file.seek(0)  # rewind to the start
            for cik in reader2:
                if cik in line:
                    writer.writerow(line)
```

However, reading a file over and over is *slow*. You'd be better of reading the whole thing into memory at the start. And the above doesn't address the other problem, namely that you are testing each row, and not each column, from `newCIK.csv`.

Read the *one* row into memory, then loop over that:

```
with open('newCIK.csv', newline='') as reader2:
    reader2 = csv.reader(reader2)
    cik_values = next(reader2)  # first row

with open('search.file', newline='') as f_in, open('SP500_10K.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_out:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in, delimiter='|')
    writer = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter='|')

    for line in reader:
        for cik in cik_values:
            if cik in line[-1]:  # test only the last column
                writer.writerow(line)
```

Note that I added in `newline=''` arguments to the `open()` calls; the `csv` module needs more control over newlines; not doing so could cause problems on Windows and when handling values containing newlines.

Demo:

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> import csv, sys
>>> newcik = '''\
... 66740,1800,1001463,1467373,896159
... '''
>>> search_file = '''\
... 1001385|NORTHWEST PIPE CO|10-Q|2015-05-06|edgar/data/1001385/0001193125-15-174814.txt
... 1001426|PERICOM SEMICONDUCTOR CORP|10-Q|2015-05-05|edgar/data/1001426/0001145443-15-000628.txt
... 1001463|Acacia Diversified Holdings, Inc.|10-K|2015-05-20|edgar/data/1001463/0001185185-15-001386.txt
... 1001463|Acacia Diversified Holdings, Inc.|10-K|2015-05-20|edgar/data/1001463/0001185185-15-001394.txt
... 1001463|Acacia Diversified Holdings, Inc.|10-Q|2015-05-20|edgar/data/1001463/0001185185-15-001388.txt
... 1001463|Acacia Diversified Holdings, Inc.|10-Q|2015-05-20|edgar/data/1001463/0001185185-15-001390.txt
... 1001463|Acacia Diversified Holdings, Inc.|10-Q|2015-05-20|edgar/data/1001463/0001185185-15-001392.txt
... 1001463|Acacia Diversified Holdings, Inc.|10-Q|2015-05-20|edgar/data/1001463/0001185185-15-001396.txt
... '''
>>> with StringIO(newcik) as reader2:
...     reader2 = csv.reader(reader2)
...     cik_values = next(reader2)  # first row
... 
>>> with StringIO(search_file) as f_in:
...     reader = csv.reader(f_in, delimiter='|')
...     writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter='|')
...     for line in reader:
...         for cik in cik_values:
...             if cik in line[-1]:  # test only the last column
...                 writer.writerow(line)
... 
1001463|Acacia Diversified Holdings, Inc.|10-K|2015-05-20|edgar/data/1001463/0001185185-15-001386.txt
103
1001463|Acacia Diversified Holdings, Inc.|10-K|2015-05-20|edgar/data/1001463/0001185185-15-001394.txt
103
1001463|Acacia Diversified Holdings, Inc.|10-Q|2015-05-20|edgar/data/1001463/0001185185-15-001388.txt
103
1001463|Acacia Diversified Holdings, Inc.|10-Q|2015-05-20|edgar/data/1001463/0001185185-15-001390.txt
103
1001463|Acacia Diversified Holdings, Inc.|10-Q|2015-05-20|edgar/data/1001463/0001185185-15-001392.txt
103
1001463|Acacia Diversified Holdings, Inc.|10-Q|2015-05-20|edgar/data/1001463/0001185185-15-001396.txt
103
```

The `103` numbers are the number of bytes written in each `writer.writerow()` call, echoed by the REPL.